# How to set timezone on a UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

Is there any way to set a `UIDatePicker`'s timezone to mine (e.g. GMT+3)?

I have tried a lot of solutions on the internet, yet none work.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker):

> Configuring a Date Picker The configuration of a date picker is
>   determined by the datePickerMode property, whose value you can set
>   programmatically or in Interface Builder. For modes that include date
>   or time values, you can also configure the locale, calendar, and time
>   zone information as appropriate. The date picker uses that information
>   when formatting date and time values for the current user, and
>   defaults to the device’s locale, calendar and time zone. The date
>   property represents the currently selected date in the form of an
>   NSDate object, which is calendar and time zone agnostic.

You can set the time zone by configuring the date picker. `TimeZone.current` will initialise a TimeZone object with the devices current time zone. You can also configure the calendar or locale if needed (though they default to the current device setting).

```
var picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.calendar = Calendar.current
picker.locale = Locale.current
picker.timeZone = TimeZone.current
```

You can retrieve the current date with the `picker.date` property. This can also be set programmatically to animate the date picker to that value.

---

You can use the date from the datepicker separately as well. You need a [date formatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) to apply calendar and timezone information:

```
let date = picker.date
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// Optionally set calendar, timezone etc on formatter
print(formatter.string(from: date))
```

Comment: Will Try it Thanks

Comment: Sorry For The Late Reply, I lost my account and finally got it back. It didn't work as intended. You See I want to make an app where you get an email with the time written on it. The Time shows GMT time instead of GMT + 3, i have tried searching this up but haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: @MyzXI You might just need to change the date based on current timezone in the picker view delegate functions or other code block.

Comment: Lol, how to do that tho?

Comment: @MyzXI I'm not at my computer now but will think of an example.

Comment: @MyzXI I have posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func onValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
print(sender.date.description(with: .current))
```

}

Reference:
Swift | iOS | XCode - UIDatePicker timezone problem fix
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B9TyvFugy8